# testing output buffering with phpspec

Tags: phpspec

Given the following PHPUnit code, how do I translate this to a phpspec test?

```
$content = 'Hello world!';
ob_start();
$this->displayer->output($content);
$output = ob_get_clean();
$this->assertEquals($content, $output);
```

What `$this->displayer->output($content)` does is simply `echo` the `$content`:

```
class Displayer {
    public function display(string $content) { echo $content; }
}
```

Comment: Can you please post the code of the class you want to spec?

Comment: @gvf I have updated the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is the only way:

```
use PHPUnit\Framework\Assert;

public function it_outputs_a_string()
{
    $content = 'Hello world!';
    ob_start();      
    $this->display($content);
    $output = ob_get_clean();

    Assert::assertEquals($content, $output);
}
```

Comment: Your answer will work. It doesn't give a phpspec native solution and given no other answers (at this moment) I take it also to mean that such doesn't exist (yet).

Comment: Instead of `PHPUnit\Framework\Assert::assertEquals` you can use https://github.com/BossaConsulting/phpspec2-expect